# How to desialize Aerospike record in Go?

Tags: go, aerospike

I am having quite complex schema in aerospike:-

```
﻿DATA SCHEMA:
bin name: user_ids
Type: List of Strings

bin name: user_w
Type: List of Integers

bin name: users
Type: map<String<List>> where list is again list(size 3) of lists each of type String
```

I am able to read this schema directly into Java object with following data structure:-

```
        userIds = (List<String>) r.getList("user_ids");
        userWeights = (List<String>) r.getList("user_w");
        users = (Map<String, List>) r.getValue("users");
```

However my following go struct is not able to retrieve it. Its coming as empty. Is something wrong with the struct schema?

```
type AudienceRecord struct {
    user_ids []string
    user_w  []int64
    users   map[string][][]string
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your user_w schema is either List of integers, or list of strings ?
Because your java and go schemas aren't equivalent here.
That is why Go struct is not able to parse your aerospike data.

Comment: Thanks, It skipped my attention. Thanks!